# How to merge 2 structs

Tags: go

I am trying to modify some stuff in Go. I have the following struct I created

I have an API call returning something like this

```
MyStruct struct {
    DID              string `bson:"d_id" json:"d_id"`
    PID              string `bson:"p_id" json:"p_id"`
    ...
}
```

in one call in the code, I want to append a new key to that struct

like

```
myNewStruct {
        DID              string `bson:"d_id" json:"d_id"`
        PID              string `bson:"p_id" json:"p_id"`
        ...
        MyNewKey         string `bson:"new_key" json:"new_key"`
}
```

The thing is, I want to add a new key, and keep the rest at the root of the object, like the object above. without having to rewrite the full object structure, or doing a for loop of each key.

```
type MyNewStruct struct {
    *MyStruct
    MyNewKey MyValueType
}
```

I have, two variable with the data,

`MyStructData` and `MyNewKeyData`

I want to, but don t know how to merge those two data inside `MyNewStruct` so that everything in MyStructData will be at the root of the key, and everything in `MyNewKeyData` will be indise the key `MyNewKey`

I am trying stuff like

```
    theObjectIWant := MyNewStruct {
        MyStructData,
        "MyNewKey" : MyNewKeyData 
    }
```

but doesn't work

Comment: Chris Taylor's answer looks like what you're looking for. I just want to comment on the terminology of Golang. What you mean by "key" is called "field" in Golang, e.g. `DID` & `PID` are fields of `MyStruct`. Not to be confused with "key" in "map".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you create an anonymous member in a struct, the compiler generates a name for the member that is named the same as the type. You can use this name when initializing the containing struct.

Here is a simplified example

```
type MyStruct struct {
    DID string
    PID string
}

type MyNewStruct struct {
    MyStruct
    MyNewKey string
}

ms := MyStruct{
    DID: "did",
    PID: "pid",
}

m := MyNewStruct{
    MyStruct: ms,
    MyNewKey: "test",
}
```

Comment: Be careful with json Marshaling/Unmarshaling though!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I fully understand what your looking for, but this may help.

```
type MyStruct struct {
   DID string
   PID string
}

type myNewStruct struct {
   MyStruct
   newKey string
}

func main() {
   s1 := MyStruct{DID: `bson:"d_id" json:"d_id"`}
   s2 := myNewStruct{MyStruct: s1, newKey: `bson:"new_key" json:"new_key"`}
   fmt.Println(s2.DID)
   fmt.Println(s2.newKey)
}
```